# Xlib's `Window` vs. GLX's `GLXWindow` confusion

Tags: opengl, window, xlib, glx

I'm looking through all sorts of example codes for **OpenGL** context creation with **GLX** and I'm confused about the two types of window objects: `Window` used by **Xlib** and `GLXWindow` used by **GLX**, because in some example codes they use Xlib's windows directly for rendering, while in others they additionally create GLX's windows.
My questions are:

1. What's the difference between those two?
2. Do I need to create both, or just `Window` will do?

The GLX 1.4 documentation (are there any more recent ones?) tells me to create the `GLXWindow` using `glXCreateWindow`, and this one takes `Window` as its third parameter. I'm not sure if this is supposed to be a parent window for `GLXWindow`, or that the `Window` is getting "wrapped" by `GLXWindow`, the documentation seems to be unclear on this. Does anyone know how is this supposed to work and the rationale behind it? And why some examples use `GLXWindow`s, and some of them don't, and yet they still seem to be working just fine?

Another thing that confuses me is that some examples use `glXCreateContext` for creating their OpenGL contexts, while others (including the GLX 1.4 specification) use `glXCreateNewContext`. Both seem to be available in my version of the library, but I don't quite get what's the difference between them.

There's also `glXMakeCurrent` and `glXMakeContextCurrent` – another source of confusion for me.

Could anyone please explain me the differences between these slightly differently spelled functions / types, or send me to some online resources where I could learn about that myself?

Oh, one more thing: Is this stuff still relevant for modern OpenGL (the 3.0+, programmable pipeline one)? Or just some legacy junk I shouldn't be bashing my poor pony head against? :q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I never hear about **GLXWindow**, I become curious what is it. Most discussions, [do not clarify](https://community.khronos.org/t/any-reason-to-use-glxcreatewindow/65043/6) why this one is necessary, and spread only guesses, including my answer.

First thing to clarify, is that **GLXWindow** has been introduced in **[GLX 1.3](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glx1.3.pdf)**. Older versions, including **[GLX 1.2](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glx1.2.ps)** define the following list of **GLXDrawable**: {**Window**, **GLXPixmap**}, with GLXPixmap created from off-screen X **Pixmap**. Specs does not clarify why GLXPixmap is needed on top of X Pixmap, while X Window can be used directly, but the guess is that something is missing in X Pixmap definition, which GLX needs to store within GLXPixmap...

**GLX 1.3** extended the definition of **GLXDrawable** as { **GLXWindow**, **GLXPixmap**, **GLXPbuffer**, **Window** }. So that you can see a new item **GLXPbuffer**, which was an attempt to improve off-screen rendering before Frame Buffer Objects (FBO) was introduced in OpenGL itself. Unlike pixmaps and windows, **GLXPbuffer** is created from scratch and has no relation in X. There is also a new **GLXWindow** with the note:

> For backwards compatibility with GLX versions 1.2 and earlier,
>   a rendering context can also be used to render into a Window.

So that **GLXWindow** looks more like an attempt to unify API (and internal logic) across all **GLXDrawable**, rather than a tool which fixes something, as it doesn't extend capabilities of X Window from a first glance.

Does **GLXWindow** introduce something new? Actually, it does! **GLX 1.3** also introduced a new function **[glXSelectEvent()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glXSelectEvent.xml)**, which allows to process GLX-specific events within X11 stream. So that the function works with GLXWindow and GLXPbuffer, but not with X Window (as it has been specifically created to distinguish GLX events from normal ones). Confusingly, the only GLX-specific event defined by specs is of type **GLXPbufferClobberEvent**, which seems more relevant to obsolete PBuffers and Window ancillary buffers (replaced by FBOs nowadays in core OpenGL specs).

*Therefore, personally I see no any practical reason for creating **GLXWindow** instead of using X Window itself* rather than just following GLX specs recommendation (stating that using X Window is only for compatibility with applications written against older GLX versions) and using "cleaned up" API.

Concerning **glXCreateNewContext()** vs **glXCreateContext()**, this is related to introduction of **GLXFBConfig**, as X **Visual** definition has been found insufficient to represent all necessary details. From specs:

> Calling glXCreateContext(dpy, visual, share list, direct) is
>   equivalent to calling glXCreateNewContext(dpy, config, render type,
>   share list, direct) where config is the GLXFBConfig identified by the
>   GLX_FBCONFIG_ID attribute of visual.

Concerning **glXMakeCurrent()** vs **glXMakeContextCurrent()**, the latter one introduced by newer GLX versions allows using different drawable and readable buffers in similar way as modern FBOs allow this, which is also clear from specs:

> Calling glXMakeCurrent(dpy, draw, ctx) is equivalent to calling
>   glXMakeContextCurrent(dpy, draw, draw, ctx). Note that draw will be
>   used for both the draw and read drawable.

Concerning modern OpenGL 3+ usage, GLX is no problem here - just use GLX extensions like **[GLX_ARB_create_context_profile](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/GLX_ARB_create_context.txt)** to create context (current Mesa library implementation provides higher OpenGL versions when creating **Core Profile**, but there usually no such different in case of proprietary drivers).

Of course, you may consider using **EGL** instead (but it rather limits OpenGL context abilities as some options are missing compared to GLX) or Wayland/Mir stuff, if you are fanatic to new display servers and want to get rid of X from dependencies (Wayland implements Xlib compatibility layer, so that it is not a show stopper for now).